# How to define maximum size for mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any way how to define maximum size for mysql database?

For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE `foo` WITH maxSize=1gb;
```

Comment: No such feature/option. You may do this on the filesystem level - but remember that the database directory total size may exceed total data size many-many times.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to setting a hard size limit is when defining the size of the InnoDB system tablespace. See documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html#innodb-startup-data-file-configuration

Example:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:12M:autoextend:max:500M
```

Note that you would not be able to use file-per-table tablespaces or general tablespaces if you did set this size limit. You'd set `innodb_file_per_table=OFF` and all tables would share the system tablespace.

This will get very uncomfortable if you need to do any ALTER TABLE or OPTIMIZE TABLE operations and there isn't enough free space in the system tablespace. You may get into a situation where you *can't* do those operations without dropping or truncating some tables, or else temporarily using `innodb_file_per_table=ON`.

There is no feature in MySQL to set a maximum size on a file-per-table tablespace or a general tablespace.

Also in modern versions of MySQL, there are still other files created outside the system tablespace, like for temporary tables and the rollback segment and the doublewrite buffer. I don't think the size of these can be controlled in the same way.

Then there are query logs and binary logs, which can take a lot of space depending on your rate of traffic.